# Uploading a document to an S3 bucket through an API Gateway and a Lambda corrupts the document

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I currently have a project that I feel is pretty straight-forward. React & Express API that allows files to be uploaded to an S3 bucket. When I run both projects locally, it works correctly. I can choose a file, even add custom metadata, and the file ends up the bucket and I can download and see it is intact.

When I deploy to AWS, I am putting my Express API in a Lambda and I use an API Gateway to have my front-end call it.

However I am running into problems in the following scenarios:

1. If I run the UI locally and point it to the API Gateway
2. I deploy the UI to a different S3 bucket made specifically for the UI and point it to the API Gateway

In both of these situations the file ends up in the S3 bucket where I want to store it, however in both these situations, the file is almost double the size of the actual file and it appears to be corrupted. If I download the file from the bucket, they can no longer be opened.

This does not occur when uploading a basic .txt file

This suggests to me I am missing some important configurations options within the API Gateway since that seems to the be the only difference.

In the API Gateway I have added `*/*` to the Binary Media Types based off some articles I have read researching this problem. Based off my reading, it suggests it has to do with how the file might be handled during upload but I am unsure of how to fix it.

Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: Going to guess that the upload was base64-encoded. Also, you should consider other options for uploading to S3 than proxying via Lambda. For example vending pre-signed URLs to your client so it can upload directly to S3, or API Gateway S3 proxy feature (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/integrating-api-with-aws-services-s3.html).

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I might be confused about which proxy feature you are referring to. Our Lambda is using an API Gateway proxy so the UI isn't calling the Lambda directly. Our API doe some other heavy-lifting like Cognito user authorization checks and what not. The UI and API upload without problems when running locally which led me to the idea there was a problem with how the API Gateway was configured. Your comment in regards to base64 looks relevant. Is there something specific we need to do to handle this situation? Thank you for looking at my question.

Comment: I'm assuming that because you are using Express, your client uploads the file to Lambda/Express, and then your Lambda uploads it to S3. So, your Lambda function is proxying an upload to S3. You should try to avoid proxying uploads, especially large uploads, in Lambda. On the API Gateway integration, I'd double-check the docs at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-payload-encodings.html